# Separate Images for App Icon and for App Store in iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, appicon

Is it acceptable by Apple (**as its not mentioned in any guidelines**, so asking if anyone has gone through this) to use different 1024x1024 image for App Store than one used for other App Icons?

So other app icons like app icon, settings, spotlight, notifications etc use one image but only App Store image is different.
Different means it has App Icon plus some text.

Comment: Whether Apple will or won't accept your app for distribution through its platform isn't a programming question, and [thus off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839).

Answer (score 2):

> Is it acceptable by Apple

We are programmers, not oracles. What Apple will do is utterly unknown and is not a programming question. To find out what will happen, try it!

However, I would say: Probably not. I tried that once and my app was rejected because the App Store icon didn’t match the app icon.